# JWT token data access from action/controller layer

Tags: jwt, .net-core

I am implementing .Net Core application with OAuth 2.0 JWT authorization and authentication.

In action/controller layer I need an access to JWT payload data of current user 
(or JWT token as it is).

How is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
this.User
```

in your Controller/Action.
If you need claims add `.Claims`