# How to access Token data from controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identity, jwt

How do I access jwt token data passed from a client to my controller method? I need the userId from the token in order to access more data about the user through other method calls within my data repository layer.

I have been able to do it with a hardcoded token string, but not from a token passed from a client. How would I write this controller method to take the jwt token as an input... or access the token string from within this controller method and thus retrieve the data I am looking for?

*How do I actually pass the token into my controller method?*

```
[HttpGet("tokenz")]
        public ApplicationUser ParseToken()
        {
            var stringToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJXaWxsQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6IjMxMWM3ZGU5LTcxMDctNGI4MC1hMzViLTA4NjJlYTE1MjZjOCIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNvYXAub3JnL3dzLzIwMDUvMDUvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL25hbWVpZGVudGlmaWVyIjoiYzE3ZTEyNWItYmE0NC00N2MxLTg2NzUtOTc2ZmJlZDRlMTEyIiwiZXhwIjoxNTc2NDU0NDYxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1NzA5NiIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjU3MDk2In0.VtsMgq7fc17M6y8kKHQRw3vO3M7aSrQgF62gw0-mXWg";

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(stringToken) as JwtSecurityToken;

            var tokenSubject = tokenS.Subject;

            var appUser = _unitofWork.User.GetUserFromSubject(tokenSubject);

            return appUser;
        }
```

This has not worked:

[JWT token data access from action/controller layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559490/jwt-token-data-access-from-action-controller-layer)

Or this:

[Retrieving access token in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240080/retrieving-access-token-in-controller)

Sooo...

```
Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        [HttpPost("moretokenz")]
        public JwtSecurityToken MoreToken(string strToken)
        {
            //Where would strToken come from?
            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(strToken);
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get()
{
    var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    return token;
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: what program do you do these animations? Great way to demonstrate how things work.

Comment: How did you know to use the string "access_token"?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to get the claims in the payload of the JWT Token. 
Visit https://jwt.io/introduction/

```
var securityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        if (securityTokenHandler.CanReadToken(yourStringAccessToken))
        {
            var decriptedToken = securityTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(yourStringAccessToken);
            var claims = decriptedToken.Claims;
            //At this point you can get the claims in the token, in the example I am getting the expiration date claims
            //this step depends of the claims included at the moment of the token is generated
            //and what you are trying to accomplish
            var expiredClaimValue = claims.Where(c => c.Type == "exp").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }
```

Comment: I can access the data itself when I have the string access token, but I do not know how to get "yourStringAccessToken" in the first place... Do I just expect the client to pass the string value access token to me? @QbaCid313

Comment: Yes, you should send the access-token from the client in the headers of your HTTP Request. 
So, assuming you are receiving requests from a client in your API endpoint, you should be able to access the Http Context object (HttpContext) at the server-side; inside this object you can access the property (Request.Headers.HeaderAuthorization). 
If you are using Bearer authorization on the client, in this object you have something similar to "Bearer <access-token>". You can get the access-token from it.

Comment: do you have an example of this in code? This is what I have been searching for but not able to actually find. Every example basically starts out with the string access token already there. (Where did it come from how did you get it, in an example.)

Comment: I only need the code for actually retrieving the token in the first place. Where was _yourStringAccessToken_ initiliazed and where was it assigned to @QbaCid313?

Comment: If you have a specific code/issue to share I will try to help you out. Usually, you get the access token from an authentication server and you can include that token on your Http request. as: `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);`